# Is it ok to do the indentation in. json file in xcode?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, configuration-files

I was forced do some change in .json config file in xcode. I was not able to do it since i cant identify the start and end of a key vlue pair. So i copied the entire text in json file clicked validate JSON in https://jsonlint.com. Did the changes and copied back.

As i expected in git it is showing the change as earlier it was one line but now in multiple line.

WIll this method going to cause any issue like to read value form JSON for the library classes ?

Comment: It should work just fine

Comment: it's ok. Indentation is not important for JSON format. In reality, JSON is just a string with formatting rules